# Usercontrol not showing in designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a custom user control:

```
<UserControl Name="ddTextBox" x:Class="UserControlsLibrary.DDTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="250" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" MinHeight="25" Height="275">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="ControlText" Height="25"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ListBox Name="ControlList" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="250"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

With the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UserControlsLibrary
{
  public partial class DDTextBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string _text;
    public string Text { get => _text ?? string.Empty; set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public DDTextBox()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      ControlText.DataContext = this;
      ControlList.DataContext = this;
      ControlText.TextChanged += TextChanged;
      ControlText.GotKeyboardFocus += KeyboardFocusChanged;
      ControlText.LostKeyboardFocus += KeyboardFocusChanged;
      ControlList.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
      ControlList.GotKeyboardFocus += KeyboardFocusChanged;
      ControlList.LostKeyboardFocus += KeyboardFocusChanged;
      IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += DDTextBox_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged;
    }

    private void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    { DItemsSource = ItemsSource.Cast<string>().ToList().FindAll(r => r.IndexOf(( (TextBox)sender ).Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0); }

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { Text = ( e.AddedItems.Count > 0 ) ? e.AddedItems[0].ToString() : string.Empty; ( (ListBox)sender ).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }

    private void KeyboardFocusChanged(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ControlList.Visibility = ( e.NewFocus == ControlList || e.NewFocus == ControlText ) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
      if ( e.OldFocus?.GetType() == typeof(ListBox) ) ( (ListBox)e.OldFocus ).SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void DDTextBox_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if ( (bool)e.OldValue == true && (bool)e.NewValue == false )
      { RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UserControlLostFocusEvent, this)); }
    }

    private void ControlLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { if ( !ControlList.IsFocused && !ControlText.IsFocused ) { ControlList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; ControlList.SelectedIndex = -1; } }

    public event RoutedEventHandler UserControlLostFocus
    {
      add { AddHandler(UserControlLostFocusEvent, value); }
      remove { RemoveHandler(UserControlLostFocusEvent, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
      private get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); SetValue(DItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dynamically generated ItemsSource based on Text property. Changes made to this may be lost. List changes should be made to the ItemsSource.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable DItemsSource
    {
      private get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(DItemsSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(DItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DItemsSourceProperty => dItemsSourceProperty;

    public static DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty => itemsSourceProperty;

    public static RoutedEvent UserControlLostFocusEvent => userControlLostFocusEvent;

    private static readonly DependencyProperty itemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DDTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty dItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DDTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

    private static readonly RoutedEvent userControlLostFocusEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("UserControlLostFocus", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(DDTextBox));

    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { if ( sender is DDTextBox control ) control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.NewValue, (IEnumerable)e.OldValue); }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable newValue, IEnumerable oldValue)
    {
      if ( oldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged )
      { oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged); }
      if ( newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newValueINotifyCollectionChanged )
      { newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged); }
    }

    void NewValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)    { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string Name = "")
    { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name)); }
  }
}
```

Referenced in my main project and added to the main window:

```
<Window Name="Main" x:Class="POSystem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myCtrls="clr-namespace:UserControlsLibrary;assembly=UserControlsLibrary"
        Title="Purchase Order" Height="850" Width="1100" Background="#FFD8D0A9">
    <Grid Name="TheGrid" Focusable="True" MouseDown="ClearFocus_OnClick" Background="Transparent">
        <myCtrls:DDTextBox x:Name="ItemsBox" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At runtime everything shows up and works as it is supposed too, however, in the window designer of the main page it does not show anything other than an outline indicating that the control is there. This outline can range from a single line at the location (only way all the functionality works proper) or if I add a minimum or just straight height it shows an empty outline of the control. How do I get this to show the (supposed to be) visible at all times textbox within the user control in the main window designer?

Comment: If in the designer there's an error, whats the error?
You can(while in the designer) click on the error to show more details,
maybe you can solve it from there?

Comment: There is no error it is just not showing the textbox that should be visible all the time. As I stated all the functionality works properly except for the control does not have any visible elements in the Main window designer

Comment: TextBox Width is binded to Path=Width but there is no Width property(In DataContext at least).

Comment: It is bound to the overall width of the user control to (as is the listbox) to accommodate width changes within the main window.

Comment: Thats not how you suppose to write it(supposed to use RelativeSource etc).
but realy you dont need to bind it at all.
Just set on both of them HorizontalAlignment=Stretch.

Comment: I get your point (best practices and all) but that does not really relate to the question seeing as doing anything like that does not change the visibility within the main window designer.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I think because of the binding no width is set, so basically it takes default value of 0.0 pixels at design time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141561/discussion-between-aridder101-and-mishka).